# php string to xml

Tags: php, xml

I'm using php v5.3. I would like to convert a string to valid xml. Xml apparently requires '&' characters to be encoded to `&amp;` but all functions I can find which do this also convert characters like 'ë' to html entities xml doesn't accept (`&euml;` in this case). What function should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` is what you need. It's a lot more selective, unlike `htmlentities`, over what it converts.

From `htmlentities` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

> This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except
>   with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity
>   equivalents are translated into these entities.

```
<?php
$a = "I love things & stuffë";
$b = htmlspecialchars($a);
$c = htmlentities($a);
echo "$b\n$c\n";
```

Outputs:

```
I love things &amp; stuffë
I love things &amp; stuff&Atilde;&laquo;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: The problem is that if he's exporting XML, wouldn't htmlspecialchars convert the tags <> and other characters?

Comment: This is what I need indeed I think, thanks. Htmlspecialchars would convert <> but that's no problem, because it is not a xml string, it just needs to be valid xml.

Answer (score 2):

If you create XML you likely have a `DOMDocument` at hand already. Even if not, you can easily create one. With a `DOMDocument` you can create text that is 100% well-formed for XML:

```
$text = "I'm using php v5.3. I would like to convert a string to valid xml. Xml apparently requires '&' characters to be encoded to &amp; but all functions I can find which do this also convert characters like 'ë' to html entities xml doesn't accept (&euml; in this case). What function should I use?";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
echo $doc->saveXML($doc->createTextNode($text));
```

This gives you the following output (verbatim):

> `I'm using php v5.3. I would like to convert a string to valid xml. Xml apparently requires '&amp;' characters to be encoded to &amp;amp; but all functions I can find which do this also convert characters like 'ë' to html entities xml doesn't accept (&amp;euml; in this case). What function should I use?`

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s&\s/', '&amp', $str);
```

That would replace all the '&' surrounded with a trailing and ending whitespace. Just work out the pattern a bit as you need

Comment: Thanks, would work indeed, but I'm not sure if & is the only character that needs to be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to convert & to `&amp;` you could try this:

```
$encoded_str = str_replace('&','&amp;',$original_str);
```

To avoid getting something like `&amp;amp;` if you originally had an `&amp;`, one way to prevent it is convert all `&amp;` to & first

```
$encoded_str = str_replace('&','&amp;',str_replace('&amp;','&',$original_str));
```

Comment: Thanks, would work indeed, but I'm not sure if & is the only character that needs to be encoded.